# Merging multiple dataframes with memory error

Tags: python, pandas, memory, merge, out-of-memory

I am trying to merge multiple dataframes but I keep getting memory error...
Does anyone have a good way to do this for loop without causing memory issue?
There are about 60 dataframes... Thanks in advance!

```
dataframe_fundamental_base = response_fundamental[0].df()
dataframe_fundamental_base['Ticker'] = dataframe_fundamental_base.index
dataframe_fundamental_base['Year'] = dataframe_fundamental_base['PERIOD_END_DATE'].dt.year
dataframe_fundamental_base.head()

for i in range(1,len(response_fundamental)):
    #Prepare a dataframe
    dataframe_fundamental_to_add = response_fundamental[i].df()
    dataframe_fundamental_to_add['Ticker'] = dataframe_fundamental_to_add.index
    dataframe_fundamental_to_add['Year'] = dataframe_fundamental_to_add['PERIOD_END_DATE'].dt.year
    cols_to_use = dataframe_fundamental_to_add.columns.difference(dataframe_fundamental_base.columns)
    #Combine 
    dataframe_fundamental_base = pd.merge(dataframe_fundamental_base, 
    dataframe_fundamental_to_add[cols_to_use], left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the use case that you have to merge 60 dataframes together? Also what is the size of each of these dataframes?

Comment: Hi NYC Coder. Each dataframe is about 180kb. Each dataframe contains a list of ticker, date and one type of financial data (revenue, for example). I am trying to use it for financial analysis.

Comment: Its hard to tell without looking at the data. I ran a test merging 60 dataframes together and it was fine.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MfWNPldfylYmXihrqpCzdWoAvbyv7rRt/view?usp=sharing This is what the dataframes look like. The shape is (14660, 5 or 4) each...